# Need to change all values in a specific row and specific column that intersect to zero

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The array is intialized with random numbers ranging between 0-20.
And if any value in that array is 0, this method should change all the values in that row and column to zero.

Instead it wipes out the array and changes all values to zero.
Any thoughts?

```
     for (int row = 0; row < size; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++){
            if (matrix[row][col] == 0){
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                    matrix[k][col] = 0;
                for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
                    matrix[row][l] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            System.out.printf("[%1$2s]", copy[i][j]);
        System.out.println();    
    }
```

Comment: Why are you changing "matrix" array and printing "copy" array? Everything should be right with matrix[][] and copy might be another array initialized earlier with zeroes, which you get.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still cares, here is the full code

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++){
            if (matrix[row][col] == 0){
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                    matrix[k][col] = 0;
                for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
                    matrix[row][l] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            System.out.printf("[%1$2s]", matrix[i][j]);
        System.out.println();    
    }
```